# Npm run production Missed semicolon error

Tags: laravel, npm, sass

When I run `npm run dev` it compiles everything with no error but when I try to run `npm run production` I get this error:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js - 
-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel- 
mix/setup/webpack.config.js

92% chunk asset optimization 
OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPluginCssSyntaxError: C:\css\themes\default- 
theme.css:3:19: Missed semicolon
at Input.error 
(C:\Users\me\projects\blog\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:130:16)
at Parser.checkMissedSemicolon
```

heres my css file

```
 var map = {
"./af": "./node_modules/moment/locale/af.js",
"./zh-hk.js": "./node_modules/moment/locale/zh-hk.js",
"./zh-tw": "./node_modules/moment/locale/zh-tw.js",
"./zh-tw.js": "./node_modules/moment/locale/zh-tw.js"};


function webpackContext(req) {
var id = webpackContextResolve(req);
return __webpack_require__(id);
}
function webpackContextResolve(req) {
if(!__webpack_require__.o(map, req)) {
    var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
    e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
    throw e;
}
return map[req];
}
webpackContext.keys = function webpackContextKeys() {
return Object.keys(map);
};
webpackContext.resolve = webpackContextResolve;
module.exports = webpackContext;
webpackContext.id = "./node_modules/moment/locale sync recursive^\\.\\/.*$";
```

ANSWER: I fixed error by adding

```
  plugins: [
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
  ]
```

to webpack.mix.js in my root directory

Comment: There appears to be a problem on the 3rd line of the code you posted. The function declaration is incomplete.

Comment: @Jeemusu Sorry, Updated with entire file.

Comment: What is the contents of "default- 
theme.css" ?  The errors shows there is a problem on line 3 character 19.

Comment: @Jeemusu the last section of code is the default-theme.css , it gets generated by npm run dev

Comment: downgrade the laravel-mix to 3

Comment: I'll try that when I return to that project thank you

Answer (score 1):

Got rid of the error by inserting:

```
 plugins: [
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
]
```

to webpack.mix.js however this is not a fix it just allows for npm run production to run.